# Fit f(x,y,z)=0 to a set of 3D points using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, implicit, data-fitting

The statement is the following:

*Given a 3D set of points (x,y,z), fit a surface defined by a certain number of parameters IMPLICITLY*

I'm definitely no expert in programming, but I need to get this done in one way or another. I've considered other programs, such as OriginPro, which can solve this problem pretty easily, but I want to have it done in MATLAB.

The surface is defined by:

```
A*x^2+B*y^2+C*z^2+D*x+E*y+F*z+G*xy+H*xz+I*yz+J=0
```

Considering that the Curve Fitting Toolbox can only fit explicit functions, what would you guys suggest?

**IMPORTANT REMARK: I'm not asking for a solution, just advice on how to proceed**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be chalked up to solving a linear system of equations where each point forms a constraint or equation in your system.  You would thus find the right set of coefficients in your surface equation that satisfies all points.  Using the equation in your question as is, one would find the [null space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)) of the linear system that satisfies the surface equation. What you'll have to do is given a set of `m` points that contain `x`, `y` and `z` coordinates, we can reformulate the above equation as a matrix-vector multiplication with the first argument technically being a matrix of one row and the vector being the coefficients that fit your plane.  This is important before we proceed to the null space part of this problem.

In particular, you can agree with me that we can represent the above in the following matrix-vector multiplication:

```
[x^2 y^2 z^2 x y z xy xz yz 1][A]    =    [0]
                              [B]
                              [C]
                              [D]
                              [E]
                              [F]
                              [G]
                              [H]
                              [I]
                              [J]
```

Our objective is to find the coefficients `A, B, ..., J` that would satisfy the constraint above.  Now moving onto the more general case, since you have `m` points, we can build our linear system and thus a matrix of coefficients on the left side of this expression:

```
[x_1^2 y_1^2 z_1^2 x_1 y_1 z_1 x_1*y_1 x_1*z_1 y_1*z_1 1][A]    =    [0]    
[x_2^2 y_2^2 z_2^2 x_2 y_2 z_2 x_2*y_2 x_2*z_2 y_2*z_2 1][B]    =    [0]
[x_3^2 y_3^2 z_3^2 x_3 y_3 z_3 x_3*y_3 x_3*z_3 y_3*z_3 1][C]    =    [0]
                    ...                                  [D]    =    [0]
                    ...                                  [E]    =    [0]
                    ...                                  [F]    =    [0]
                    ...                                  [G]    =    [0]
                    ...                                  [H]    =    [0]
                    ...                                  [I]    =    [0]
[x_m^2 y_m^2 z_m^2 x_m y_m z_m x_m*y_m x_m*z_m y_m*z_m 1][J]    =    [0]
```

We now build this linear system, and solve to find our coefficients.  The trick is to build the matrix that you see on the left hand side of this linear system, which I will call `M`.  Each row is such that you create `[x_i^2 y_i^2 z_i^2 x_i y_i z_i x_i*y_i x_i*z_i y_i*z_i 1]` with `x_i`, `y_i` and `z_i` being the i<sup>th</sup> `(x,y,z)` coordinate in your dataset.

Once you build this, you would thus find the null space of this system.  There are many methods to do this in MATLAB.  One way is to simply use the [`null`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/null.html) function on the matrix you build above and it will return to you a matrix where each column is a potential solution to the surface you are fitting above.  That is, each column directly corresponds to the coefficients `A`, `B`, ..., `J` that would fit your data to the surface.  You can also try using the [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular-value_decomposition) or [QR decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) if you like, but the `null` function is a good place to start as it uses singular value decomposition already.

---

I would like to point out that the above will only work if you provide a matrix that is **not** full [rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)).  To simplify things, this can happen if the number of points you have is less than the number of parameters you have.  Therefore, this method would only work if you had up to 9 points in your data.  If you have exactly 9, then this method will work very well.  If you have less than 9, then there will be more potential solutions as the number of degrees of freedom increases.  Specifically, you will have `10 - m` possible solutions and any of those solutions is valid.  If you have more than 10 points and they are all **unique**, this would be considered a full rank matrix and thus the only solution to the null space is the trivial one with the coefficients being all set to 0.

In order to escape the possibility of the null space being all 0, or the possibility of the null space providing more than one solution, you probably just want **one** solution, and you most likely have 10 or more possible points that you want to fit your data with.  An alternative method that I can provide is simply an extension of the above but we don't need to find the null space. Specifically, you relax one of the coefficients, say `J` and you can set that to any value you wish.  For example, set it to `J = 1`.  Therefore, the system of equations now changes where `J` disappears from the mix and it now appears on the right side of the system:

```
[x_1^2 y_1^2 z_1^2 x_1 y_1 z_1 x_1*y_1 x_1*z_1 y_1*z_1][A]    =    [-1]    
[x_2^2 y_2^2 z_2^2 x_2 y_2 z_2 x_2*y_2 x_2*z_2 y_2*z_2][B]    =    [-1]
[x_3^2 y_3^2 z_3^2 x_3 y_3 z_3 x_3*y_3 x_3*z_3 y_3*z_3][C]    =    [-1]
                    ...                                [D]    =    [-1]
                    ...                                [E]    =    [-1]
                    ...                                [F]    =    [-1]
                    ...                                [G]    =    [-1]
                    ...                                [H]    =    [-1]
[x_m^2 y_m^2 z_m^2 x_m y_m z_m x_m*y_m x_m*z_m y_m*z_m][I]    =    [-1]
```

You can thus find the parameters `A`, `B`, ..., `I` using [linear least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)) where the solution can be solved using the [pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse).  The benefit with this approach is that because the matrix is full rank, [there is one and **only one** solution, thus being unique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system#Approximate_solutions).  Additionally, this formulation is nice because if there is an exact solution to the linear system, solving with the pseudoinverse will provide the exact solution.  If there is no exact solution to the system, meaning that not all constraints are satisfied, the solution provided is one that minimizes the least squared error between the data and the parameters that were fit with that data.

MATLAB already has an awesome utility to solve a system through linear least squares - in fact, the core functionality of MATLAB is to solve linear algebra problems (if you didn't know that already). You can use matrix left division to solve the problem.  Simply put, given that you built your matrix of coefficients above after you introduce the relaxation of `J` also being called `M`, the solution to the problem is simply `coeff = M\(-ones(m,1));` with `m` being the number of points and `coeff` being the coefficients for the surface equation that fit your points. The `ones` statement in the code creates a column vector of ones that are negative that has `m` elements.

Using the least squares approach has a more stable and unique solution as you are specifically constraining one of the coefficients, `J`, to be 1.  Using the null space approach only works if you have less points than you do parameters and will possibly give you more than one solution so long as the coefficients span the null space. Specifically, you will get `10 - m` solutions and they are all equally good at fitting your data.

I hope this is enough to get you started and good luck!

Comment: Ah, nice answer! Tha fantastic world of Solving Ax=b!

Comment: Thank you for elaborating your answer this much! I really appreciate it, truly!

I'm currently trying to implement this on MATLAB, but at the moment one question arises: How would you estimate the goodness of the fit? Say calculating R^2 or RMSE, for example.

And again, thank you very much!

J.

Comment: @Jorge Ah well calculating the coefficient of determination assumes a linear model, which is definitely not the case here so this wouldn't be useful. You could calculate the RMSE as the solution I've provided finds the error in a least-squares sense. You can do this by noting that substituting a point using the parameters `A,...,J` in the surface equation would theoretically give 0.  In a least-squares sense, this may not be true and you will get a non-zero result. To calculate the RMSE here, simply loop over each example and substitute this into the equation, find the average and square root.

Comment: @Jorge You can do this very easily where you have already solved for the coefficients `A,...,J` and you have a matrix equation `M*coeff` with `coeff` being the coefficients for the surface. Simply perform `M*coeff` and you'll get a vector of values that should theoretically be `0` for all points but you don't get that. Find the average of these, and find the square root so: `sqrt(mean(M*coeff))` is the RMSE here.  BTW, you're very welcome! This was an interesting problem.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks man!! I've got it to work, results seem to be pretty OK!

Comment: @Jorge Awesome!  Glad you got it to work!  BTW, can you tell me which method you decided to use? Did you use the null space method, or the least-squares method?

Comment: @rayryeng For some reason the Null space method didn't quite work, as it didn't give any results. I went for the least-squares method, which seemed actually easier and worked flawlessly tbh... However, say I would like to fix any other parameter, one that is not the independent term, how would that affect the expression above?

Comment: @Jorge The independent term is the easiest one to set.  However, if you want to fix any of the other variables, it's just a matter of setting any of them to a known value, which thus produces an independent term on the left side of each equation.  Simply bring that over to the right side for each equation and solve for the other coefficients.  For example, suppose you set `A = 1`.  You would thus have `x_i^2` terms on the left for each equation.  The right side now becomes `-x_i^2`, and you would solve the system the same way.

Comment: @rayryeng I see what you did there... It really is simpler relaxing the independent term as you said. Anyway, thanks for everything mate!

Comment: @Jorge You're very welcome :).  It's questions like these that really flex my knowledge and make Stack Overflow very worthwhile. Good luck to you and your project!

Comment: @Jorge BTW, I figured out the reason why your null space was 0.  For overdetermined systems, meaning that you have more points than parameters, the null space will always be 0.  It's a natural property of the matrix.  I'll remove that portion and only leave in the least squared bit.

Comment: @rayryeng Hey there mate! I've run into a problem. The thing is that I have a different set of data that can't be fitted into an ellipsoid. What I've done is this `pinv(S)*q*-ones(n,1)` where S is the matrix you called M and n is the number of points. q is a number I change in a while loop, so, until the surface fitted doesn't meet the criteria needed for it to be an ellipsoid, `q = q + 0.001`. This doesn't work as it can't find the parameters needed to meet the needed criteria. Is there a way to impose some criteria to this method?

Comment: @rayryeng Hey mate, last question might be a little bit difficult as I've been researching. Is there a way to set bounds to the parameters?

Comment: @Jorge no not with this approach. You'll need to use linear programming instead. Check out the `linprog` function.

Comment: @Jorge Code example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34714851/3250829. You will need the optimization toolbox though.

Comment: @rayryeng Hello there Ray, I have been doing some research on `linprog` and as far as I can tell, it can't take nonlinear constrains. So, maybe, the appropiate function to use is `fmincon` or something similar to that. Problem is I'm having a hard time figuring out what the objetive function is. My guess would be the quadric equation, but evaluated for every single data point, leaving A, B, C, ... as unknowns, therefore I'd have as much equations as data points. Would that be correct? If so, then I can't use `fmincon` since it's thought to be used for single objetive function optimization.

Comment: I'm not sure. This is going beyond my expertise. Sorry.

Comment: @rayryeng  it's ok! I think I've came up with a decent solution to my problem. But tbh, I don't think I would have come this far without you. I sincerely thank you!